# Is it always bad to use vue-component data as an object?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

According to the [official vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-data-essential), component data must be a function.

In my situation, i want to get data with an axios call and store this data in a component.

The problem is, if a declare this data as a function as the documentation advice to, every time i will need this component it will do a new axios call.

My main goal using vue-components was to minimize axios calls by re-using components-data through my vues, to improve performance.

Am i wrong to use vue-components in this situation?

EDIT: here's some code to clarify my question:

What the documentation recommend to do (data is a function which returns data, which means it will do the axios call everytime you want to use the data i guess.):

```
Vue.component('user-infos', {
        data() {
            userInfos = axios.get('ajax/getInfosFiche.php?action=UserInformations')
        }
    });
```

What i did (data is an object, which means if multiple vues use it and one modify the data, it will be modified for all the vues) :

```
Vue.component('user-infos', {
    data: {
        userInfos = axios.get('ajax/getInfosFiche.php?action=UserInformations')
    }
});
```

Comment: could you explain your use case with some code snippets?

Comment: Of course, i will edit my post to add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a data store, that holds your data and can be used from different components.
You could for example take a look at [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/).

Another way is to define your own custom store, which does not need to be as heavy as VueX.
One way to do this is create and export an [observable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) object and import it from the components that need to have access to the store.

The way I am currently using it is by making the store object available through a global mixin. That way, every component has access to "this.$store" which holds my data.

```
const state = Vue.observable({ data: {} });

Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    $store: {
      get: function() {
        return state.data;
      },
      set: function(newData) {
        state.data = newData;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can see the full example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-store-uj30i).

[Example Implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-store-uj30i)